# Google People API - How to get a user profile photo of a certain size, if it is not .jpg but .png

Tags: google-oauth, google-people-api

Good day.

Tell me, please, is it possible to reduce the profile photo of the user, if it is .png, and not .jpg

The fact is that the site has authorization through social networks, during authorization, we get a photo of the user, which we then use in the output of the avatar of his comments.

It happens that people upload huge photos for their google avatars and the link to them is also inserted into the img tag as a source, for photos like .jpg there is an opportunity to request its reduced size, but not for .png.

Example google user avatar link in .png format:

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AAuE7amADg1dgDNpDnOAKONPyUkZVJJh56kwRXGE812tWPEOp

Example google user avatar link in resized .jpg format:

https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-AJHQJsYSgJQQ/AAAAABAAdAAAI/AAAAaAAAAAAA/ACHi3rzc3h8GccE4aQl70zIZ3haKt12O5-BXW753kw/photo.jpg?sz=50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for resizing the user profile photo retrieved with the people API is

`https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/ID_OF_THE_PHOTO=s[REPLACE_BY_A_PIXEL_VALUE]`, e.g.

`https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AAuE7amADg1dgDNpDnOAKONPyUkZVJJh56kwRXGE812tWPEOp=s200`

This works for any image format, see [here](https://developers.google.com/people/image-sizing) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, that helped.

But it’s not clear why, during authorization, some links come in this form, but this is a completely different story)